Use Python Selenium to get data from two elements type value under a main XPath
The number of rows and sequence is not fix. It is random.. The attached image shown only two type of html row.
Type A row are 2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15, I would like to extract the data of class = "message-in focusable-list-item....." (highlighted in green).
Type B row are 1,6,11,14. I would like to extract tableindex = "-1".
enter image description here
I have tried using the following method to get the value from Type A row with given XPath. It worked.
msgInOutPath = '//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[8]/div/div'
msgInOut = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, msgInOutPath)))
classValue = msgInOut.get_attribute('class')
print(f'Class: {classValue}')

mainXPath = '//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]'
The problem is Type A and Type B sequence is random. Number of rows also random.

How can I check if the row is Type A or Type B under the main XPath and get the data I want?

Thank you in advance for all the pro tips!

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

Please share a link to the page. We're unlikely to be able to help without it.

Why are you trying to print the class values and tabindex of these DIVs? That doesn't seem terribly useful. I'm assuming there's a next step in this process that you haven't revealed yet.

If you look at the HTML provided, you will see a pattern to the two types of DIVs that you are referring to.
Type A looks like
<div class role="row">

Type B looks like
<div class="_amjw _amk1 _aot1 focusable-list-item" tabindex="-1">

So we can grab these DIVs, do a simple check to see if it contains the attribute "role", and that splits them into either Type A or B. From there you can grab the info you want.
I would do it like this...
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
divs = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(...))
for div in divs:
    if div.get_attribute("role") == "row":
        # Type A
        class_value = div.find_element("div > div").get_attribute("class")
    else:
        # Type B
        table_index = div.get_attribute("tabindex")

The part I can't provide is the locator ... in the wait. You haven't provided enough HTML to be able to determine that but basically you want a locator that pulls all the Type A/B DIVs into divs. From there, the rest should be straightforward.

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
Xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]'
divs = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, Xpath)))
for div in divs:
if div.get_attribute("class role") == "row":
# Type A
class_value = div.find_element("div > div").get_attribute("class")
print(f'class_value: {class_value}')
else:
# Type B
table_index = div.get_attribute("tabindex")
print(f'table_index: {table_index}')
The code is working, but it only loop once.

Thank you so much! Your suggested code is working, but it only loop once. How do i made it to loop through to check all its ''child div''.

Use print(len(divs)) before the for. What does it print? I'm assuming 1.

Use the main_x_path to find all the rows within that section. Loop through each row element. Inside the loop, use another XPath expression to check for specific identifiers of Type A or Type B rows.
for i in range(1, len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(main_x_path+ "/div")) + 1):
    row_xpath = maix_x_path + f"/div[{i}]"
    row_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, row_xpath)))

    # Check for Type A
    if i in [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15]:  # Adjust based on your list
        msgInOutPath = row_xpath + "/div/div"  # Assuming message element is nested within another div
        msgInOut = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, msgInOutPath)))
        classValue = msgInOut.get_attribute('class')
        print(f'Type A, Class: {classValue}')
    
    # Check for Type B
    elif i in [1, 6, 11, 14]:  # Adjust based on your list
        table_index_element = row_element.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@tableindex='-1']") 
        table_index_value = table_index_element.text  .get_attribute('tableindex') if needed
        print(f'Type B, tableindex: {table_index_value}')

    # Handle cases where the row doesn't belong to either type
    else:
        print(f'Unidentified row type at position {i}')

